# Is there any disadvantage with transmitting the same excitation signal to several resolvers (basically rotating transformers)?

Tags: transformer, analog, inductance

I am considering sending the same excitation signal to multiple resolvers (i.e. transformers of which the secondary rotates with respect to the primary) used as angle sensors in the joints of a robotic arm. As long as the source is capable of driving these loads (in fact, the inductance seen by the transmitter would be divided by the number of sensors, since the excitation windings would be in parallel), I don't see any issue with this but perhaps I am not seeing the entire picture. Accuracy is highly important.

The transmitter will be custom-made, not bought.

I'm considering an excitation signal around 12V in amplitude, 0.5 turn ratio with secondary, and 1kHz in frequency.

What do you think?

I'm willing to simulate on simscape any schematic you may use to illustrate what you say.

Comment: Can you please comment on Andy's query re bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is there any disadvantage with transmitting the same excitation signal
>   to several resolvers (basically rotating transformers)?*

Well, going back to some old-fashioned positional systems used on-board ships (for instance), that's exactly what they did and there was no option. One synchronous resolver was operated manually from some desk /back-office situation and it remotely turned (as an example) an antenna fastened to its interconnected resolver. This type of system has no-option other than to share the same excitation signal so, the precedent is already set: -

[image]

Image from [Moog synchro handbook](https://www.moog.com/literature/MCG/synchrohbook.pdf) page 2-2.

The last point mentioned in the article above (multiple receivers decrease accuracy) is not about R1 and R2 sharing but about S1-S2-S3 sharing and this does not apply when doing an "electronic" decode of position. This question is about R1 and R2 sharing.

So, the precedent is set but the question then sort of boils down to how many different loads can you connect to a power supply without creating some disadvantage. As EEs we should all know about these things: -

- Don't overload a power supply (AC or DC)
- Don't use high inrush loads that might upset other loads using the same power feed.
- Don't generate too much noise that can back-feed to other loads.

All these problems are solved by good design practices.

Comment: @MisterMystère - I've flagged your comment and told the mods this: *Bounty given to wrong answer by mistake - can this be put right please - he meant to give it to me.*

Comment: @MisterMystère are you actively trying to sort out the problem of giving bounty to the wrong answer?

Comment: Sorry, I thought your flag mentioned above would make them do it or at least contact me - I have not heard anything back since your comment. I'm going to flag that as well.

Comment: Oddly enough even my comment about this seems to have been deleted?

Comment: How bizarre @MisterMystère

Comment: I asked about it, bounties are final once awarded.

Comment: OK, you did your best @VoltageSpike

Answer (score 2):

I can forsee several possible issues with what you're proposing.

One, the reference excitation drive is probably gain-controlled based on the return signals, so its drive is tuned and adjusted specific to that resolver. The decoder relies on knowing that reference to properly demodulate the X and Y return signals.

Two, impedance control and signal integrity. Having two reference windings on the same driver isn't clean. There will be reflections and mismatch issues, so the quality of the reference signal will be compromised with distortion.

Three, crosstalk interference between multiple resolvers. I think you'd want to avoid that as much as possible, so keeping their signals away from each other is important. This includes isolating the reference winding drives.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (+1). 1/ Why should the excitation be controlled in amplitude when the ratio alone of the sine and cosine signals is important (even when the local carrier is multiplied with the s/c signals)? I can make sure the transmitter is not done this way. 2/ Why would there need to be impedance control at 2kHz, and even if there was, what would be the issue with adapting the line to the impedance of the resolver primary at the excitation frequency? 3/ Do you mean from the mutual inductance? Would you care to expand with a schematic illustrating the disturbances so I can study it?

Comment: The decoding depends on both amplitude and phase of the X and Y signal. These are compared against the reference to determine the polarity, and thus what quadrant they are in. X and Y also need to be amplitude calibrated, and have an optimal reference drive level set *for that resolver*. Impedance mismatches from reflections will cause distortions on your reference signal, which will show up as unwanted harmonics in your return signals. Finally, cross-coupling another reference coil via shared drive can (and probably will) also add unwanted harmonics due to the operation of the other coils.